# Partial export: expanding #+INCLUDE keywords

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-ref

I wrote a code that clones the current org buffer, performs a transformation of the links (which are `org-ref` citations) and then exports that temporary buffer. The problem is that the links in the `#INCLUDE`-ed files are not transformed. I would like to perform expansion of the `#+INCLUDE` keywords before putting the text into the temporary buffer (without affecting the original buffer, of course). How can I do that?

(The alternative, i.e. performing the transformation during the export of the links would result in several complications, so I do not want to pursue that path unless I must.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the amusingly named function `(org-org-export-as-org)`, which will export to a buffer named `*Org ORG Export*` with all the `#+INCLUDE` lines expanded.  Then you could do your further processing and export from that buffer.

Full documentation for the function:

```
org-org-export-as-org is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp
function in ‘ox-org.el’.

(org-org-export-as-org &optional ASYNC SUBTREEP VISIBLE-ONLY BODY-ONLY
EXT-PLIST)

Export current buffer to an Org buffer.

If narrowing is active in the current buffer, only export its
narrowed part.

If a region is active, export that region.

A non-nil optional argument ASYNC means the process should happen
asynchronously.  The resulting buffer should be accessible
through the ‘org-export-stack’ interface.

When optional argument SUBTREEP is non-nil, export the sub-tree
at point, extracting information from the headline properties
first.

When optional argument VISIBLE-ONLY is non-nil, don’t export
contents of hidden elements.

When optional argument BODY-ONLY is non-nil, strip document
keywords from output.

EXT-PLIST, when provided, is a property list with external
parameters overriding Org default settings, but still inferior to
file-local settings.

Export is done in a buffer named "*Org ORG Export*", which will
be displayed when ‘org-export-show-temporary-export-buffer’ is
non-nil.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, export to org does much more than what I need -- things like inserting `#TITLE` and `#AUTHOR` and transforming links of the form `cite:something` to links of the form `[[#something][something]]`...

Comment: You could use the BODY-ONLY argument to solve the first problem, and there is probably something you could put in EXT-PLIST to solve the second.  But your solution with `org-export-expand-include-keyword` looks better if you have already gone to the trouble of cloning the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I am beginning to suspect that, in Emacs, the best way to find out answers is to look though the source code... Looking through the code of `org-export-as` reveals the answer: `org-export-expand-include-keyword`.